# When using a gower dissimilarity matrix for use in dbscan clustering, the bools still perfectly separate the clusters

Tags: clustering, dbscan, gower-similarity

I am working on a clustering analysis where my data is a mix of bool and numeric. From research it looks like one should not do a simple kmeans with mixed data types since the extreme end of scaled data will make the bools of 1/0 dominate.

The general gist of what I found online was to use a gower difference matrix which I did using `cluster::daisy()`. But, nevertheless, both on my actual data set and on the diamonds example below, I get perfect separation in clusters based on the booleans. This must be 'wrong' since the goal of using a gower matrix was to be able to cluster on mixed data types to avoid this kind of problem. So I'm hoping someone can spot where I might have misunderstood or offer some pointers.

My Rmd script to reproduce:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, cluster, dbscan)
```

Get a shortened version of diamonds with a mix of bool and numeric data.

```
my_diamonds <- diamonds |> 
  sample_n(20000) |> 
  mutate(
    is_premium = ifelse(cut == 'Premium', 1, 0),
    is_color_def = ifelse(color %in% c('D', 'E', 'F'), 1, 0)
    ) |> 
  select(carat, is_premium, is_color_def, depth:x)
```

Create a gower difference matrix using cluster::daisy(). Specify the bool fields in `type = list(symm = c('is_premium', 'is_color_def')`.

As I understand it, since I'm calculating a difference matrix I don't have to scale or transform the data,

```
# create a gower distance matrix since we have mixed data types (bool and numeric)
gower_dist <- daisy(my_diamonds, metric = "gower", stand = T, type = list(symm = c('is_premium', 'is_color_def')))
gower_dist |> summary()


199990000 dissimilarities, summarized :
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.0000  0.1143  0.1967  0.2042  0.2895  0.6926 
Metric :  mixed ;  Types = I, S, S, I, I, I, I 
Number of objects : 20000
```

See if this plot helps choose values for eps in dbscan

```
# Determine optimal eps value to start with
dbscan::kNNdistplot(gower_dist, k = 100) # no idea what to put for K
  # no kink or 'knee'
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Run dbscan() using the difference matrix.

```
# Perform DBSCAN clustering
dbscan_result <- dbscan(gower_dist, eps = 0.02, minPts = 10) # eps from median of summary(gower_dist)

# Get cluster labels
cluster_labels <- dbscan_result$cluster

# Get noise points (not assigned to any cluster)
noise_points <- which(cluster_labels == 0)

# Get number of clusters
num_clusters <- max(cluster_labels)

cat("Number of Clusters:", num_clusters, "\n")
cluster_labels |> table()

# Print the results
my_diamonds$cluster <- cluster_labels
my_diamonds %>%
  group_by(cluster) %>%
  summarize(count = n(), across(everything(), list(avg = ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE)), .names = "{.col}_{.fn}")) %>%
  select(count, everything())
```

Results print out as:

```
Number of Clusters: 4 
cluster_labels
   0    1    2    3    4 
 197 7273 7530 2736 2264
```

And the data frame with average of each var per cluster. You can see that the bool vars highlighted are 1 or 0 indicating perfect separation:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Have I misunderstood how to use daisy with mixed data types? Must I transform my difference matrix in someway?

How can I get around this perfect separation of clusters that the boolean vars create?

[edit]
Docs page 6 for dbscan(): https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbscan/dbscan.pdf#page5

> Specifying the data
> If x is a matrix or a data.frame, then fast fixed-radius nearest neighbor computation using a kd-tree is performed using Euclidean distance. See frNN() for more information on the parameters related to nearest neighbor search. Note that only numerical values are allowed in x.

Why would it be Euclidean distance? I thought my matrix is a dissimilarity  matrix. Could I have used an inappropriate form of matrix for x with my daisy gower dissimilarity matrix?

[edit 2]

I tried adding weights when I create the dissimilarity matrix like so:

```
weights <- c(1, 0.05, 0.05, 1,1,1,1) # weights the bools tiny
gower_dist <- daisy(my_diamonds, metric = "gower", stand = T, weights = weights, type = list(symm = c('is_premium', 'is_color_def')))
```

But the issue persisted, the bools lead to perfect separation.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCqTi.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL8a9.png

Comment: (1) "This must be wrong" - not necessarily; clusterings occur that are perfectly separated on one variable. In clustering you normally want separation, so this is not in itself wrong or bad. (2) That said, I'd say you are right to be skeptical. In fact Gower's distance implicitly gives high weight to differences in categorical and binary variables. You can in principle reweight these variables, but it isn't so clear how to do this. We discuss this in a slightly different setup here: https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1467-9876.2012.01066.x

Comment: There are alternative clustering methods for mixed type data such as KAMILA, k-prototypes, and latent class analysis. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kamila/index.html https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/fpc/html/flexmixedruns.html https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2018/RJ-2018-048/index.html

Comment: Hi @ChristianHennig thanks for link and suggestions. Note my edit. dbscan is apparently still using euclidean distance on the matrix which surprised me. Is that expected? ""This must be wrong" - not necessarily;" It's just that this happened both on the example data with diamonds and with my actual data, the bools separated everything. So I think my approach is flawed. I'll try weighting if I can figure out how. Will also take a look at the other algorithms you suggested, but I was keen to try dbscan

Comment: The dbscan documentation says "if x is a matrix or a data frame". However your ````gower_dist```` is a dist object, and my interpretation of the help page is that in this case it will use your specified distance. By the way, dbscan may be particularly prone to align clusters with your binary categories as there will be density gaps between them, which is what dbscan uses to delimit the clusters. This combination may not be particularly good. The original dbscan designers were motivated by Euclidean data.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianHennig. Ok, I’m taking from this I should try another algorithm. Will take a look at the ones you suggested

Comment: I looked at the 3 links you sent @ChristianHennig. None mention bools specifically but presumably bools can be considered categorical for these. The clustMixType library looks newer and by the sounds of it, user friendly to get going with. Thanks again for the suggestions!